# Does GHC runtime access old data even if my app doesn't?

Tags: haskell, garbage-collection, ghc

I'm wondering if it's a good idea to run ghc with tons of swap space, or if it's even feasible. I have a workload where most data is idle 99% of the time. A very small set of the data is actually being actively used at any given time. This sounds like a perfect time to let the kernel swap memory, but gc is usually a problem. Haskell only has immutable values, though, so in theory it could work.

Does the ghc runtime read old values, forcing me to swap in/out on each gc or something, or can I expect memory that I'm not touching to not be swapped in?

Feel free to edit the title, I couldn't think of a good description that fit.

Comment: I'd guess GC reads everything during a major cycle, forcing the swap-in. I'm not sure about this, especially in generational GC, but it might be the case. If you have large vectors/bytestrings, those shouldn't be affected much, though.

Comment: Could the experimental "compact regions" feature help here? http://hackage.haskell.org/package/compact I'm not sure how it interacts with swapping, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GHC uses a copying collector in which the trees of live/reachable data is copied over to a new region, which means major GC pause times increase with the size of your working set which can be counterintuitive.

The property of "most data being idle" is not an uncommon one, and I think is closely related to the *generational hypothesis* which motivates generational GC, which GHC uses.

However it sounds like you're talking about something like e.g. caching a bunch of data in memory. This is known to be problematic for the reasons above (long GC pauses, or maybe bad behavior). Compact regions are a sort of experimental feature that might work as the basis of a library for working with boxed data in this way, though I don't think anyone knows if they're a good idea yet.

So it seems clear if your data is swapped out this will only make an already bad situation (long GC pauses for large working set) much worse.